# Mongo DB regex aggregation query using java API

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I want to query using regex and aggregation in mongo db, the following is working fine in mongo shell but how to write the same using Java API.

```java
    db.posts_collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$posts"},
    {$match :{"posts.message":/.*keyword.*/} })
```

I tried using the following but unable to get the required result,

```java
    BasicDBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$posts");
    BasicDBObject matchKeyWord = new BasicDBObject("$match",new
    BasicDBObject("posts.message",java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("keyword")));
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(unwind,matchKeyWord);
```

Please tell me how to write the same query in java.

Comment: Then what results *do* you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that should work, but if you really wanted to be sure use the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator form instead:

```java
    BasicDBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$posts");
    BasicDBObject matchKeyWord = new BasicDBObject(
        "$match",new BasicDBObject(
            "posts.message",new BasicDBObject("$regex",".*keyword.*")
        )
    );
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(unwind,matchKeyWord);
```

That operator exists for the purpose of "safe" serialization with differing drivers.